# See players through walls as red shadows?

Tags: call-of-duty-advanced-warfare

In Call of Duty Advanced Warfare, sometimes I can see enemy players through walls as red shadows.

They come and go, sort of long blink type of "coming and going." The effect lasts for a while, I think it must be 10-15 seconds.

Obviously this is some kind of effect created by a player.

My question is what item/perk/whatever it is that creates this effect?

I thought it would be the Threat Grenade, but I have yet to figure out how that one works, I shoot it into the area, and it detonates but it doesn't seem to show me any threat indicators. Would it have to detonate and "infect" enemy players?

Answer (score 1):

**You are correct in thinking that this is because of the threat grenade.**

[image]

This picture beautifully displays the effect of the threat grenade, temporarily displaying red over the players, which can be seen through walls. The enemy must first be hit with the threat grenade before you can see the effect.

> Threat grenades are new to Call of Duty: Advanced Warfare and can be useful in revealing enemies through walls – painting them a vivid red on your screen so you can track their movements.

[Source](http://www.vg247.com/2014/11/07/call-of-duty-advanced-warfare-multiplayer-guide-best-loadout/)

Comment: In addition to threat grenades, this can also happen if a friendly player deploys the UAV scorestreak with the Threat Detection module installed.

Comment: Also note that the screenshot is from the singleplayer, not the multiplayer. I find it extremely harder to mark enemies with the threat detection grenade in multiplayer. Also, perks exist in multiplayer to counter the effect of threat grenades.

Comment: I doubt what I'm describing and asking about is the threat grenade then since it looks completely different. The "shadows" that I describe are precisely the 3d models of the enemy players as they run around on the map, seen through walls. It sounds much more plausible that this is the UAV module that @cloudymusic mentions.

Comment: The threat detection module on a UAV works almost exactly as the threat detection grenade. So does the recon drone (another scorestreak), with which you can throw threat detection grenades to mark enemies.

Comment: Please note that in multiplayer, players using the Cold Blooded perk are immune to threat detection from UAV and threat grenades.